# C pointer behaviour, Volume II

Tags: c, pointers

Look at this:

```
int main() {

char *verse = "zappa";
printf("%c\n", *verse);
// the program correctly prints the first character

*verse++;
printf("%c\n", *verse);
// the program correctly prints the second character, which in fact lies 
// in the adjacent memory cell

(*verse)++;
printf("%c\n", *verse);
// the program doesn't print anything and crashes. Why?

return 0;
}
```

Why does my program crash as I try to increment the value pointed by verse? I was expecting something like the next character in the ASCII table.

Comment: "// the program doesn't print sh*t and crashes. Why?" LOL

Comment: that's one of the better code comments I've seen today.

Answer (score 10):

This line `(*verse)++;` modifies a string literal. That is undefined behavior.

Note that the earlier line of code `*verse++` is parsed as `*(verse++)`

Comment: But if I simply write `verse++` without the asterisk I get the same result at execution time. Strange....

Comment: In other words it increments a character at current address that verse is pointing to and that is prohibited.

Comment: @MadHatter because `verse++;` is equivalent to `*verse++;`, as it's the same as `*(verse++);`: you're dereferencing the incremented value, which is doing nothing. On the other side, `(*verse)++;` is first accessing the character, and *then* incrementing it, not the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

`verse` points to a string literal, which you're not allowed to modify. Try:

```
char verse1[] = "zappa";
char *verse = verse1;
```

Now your code will work because `verse1` is a modifiable string.

Note that `*verse++` is effectively equivalent to just `verse++`. The indirection returns the value pointed to by the pointer before the increment, but since you're not doing anything with the return value of the expression, the indirection doesn't really do anything.

Comment: VERY useful observation.